# Debugging the Javascript in my asp.net website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

My webpage contains :
 
        
            
        
        
            
        
    
I did a break points on the Tools.JS , but while debugging I didn't found my JS in Script Documents (Run Time mode) , and i remarked the exclamation message on my BP saying  that this break point willn't be take in mind cause the JS document isn't charged.

My question is : Is there another way to load a JS to be available in the debugging mode?
and how could i debug my JS in this case ?

Thanks in advance
Abdelrahman,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just writ keyword

***debugger;***

in your function 
for example

```
function avc()
{
 debugger;
 ..
 ..
}
```

for more detail : http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/DOMT-5UBUVW

Comment: But i want to know why My ScriptManager load the all my JS but didn't load the Tool.Js :

Comment: here you are my exemple:  
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="true">
        <Services>
        </Services>
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Tools.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/UserActions.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/SnapManagement.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) ? debugging js with firebug is easier than with visual studio

Comment: I have an explorer limitation , I must use the IE Explorer,, and I just want to debug it in Visual studio

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Firebug. It's an addon to Fireforx

[firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com)